# Detecting programmatically whether a specific UWP app is installed on system

Tags: c#, winforms, uwp

**Without** going through Windows Registry, is there a quicker way to detect programmatically whether a specific [Universal Windows Platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide) (UWP) app is installed on a system? App will be installed through [Windows Apps Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/best-selling/apps/pc) and its installation need to be verified from a Winform program written in C#. But the language doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use PackageManager.FindPackage or [PackageManager.FindPackageForUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager.findpackageforuser) to see if the target package is available universally or for the specific or current user.

See [Calling Windows 10 APIs From a Desktop Application](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/) for info on how to call this from your WinForms app.

Also check out the [Enumerate app packages by user SID sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Package-Manager-Inventory-5bee970a) which demonstrates enumerating app packages from a C# console app. The project used is out of date (it's for VS2013), but the overall code flow should still work.

Depending on your specific scenario (why do you need to know this and what will you do with that information?) there may be better ways for your specific use case. For example: you asked elsewhere about launching a UWP app. If you define and launch a protocol for the app you don't need to check if it's already there first as the protocol launch will offer to look for the app in the store if it's not installed.